# atan2() using two vectors

Tags: c++, geometry

Below is an example of how we can find the angle in all four quadrant wise using the function `atan2`.

```
#include <stdio.h>       
#include <math.h>       

#define PI 3.14159265

int main ()
{
  double x, y, result;
  x = -10.0;
  y = -10.0;
  result = atan2 (y,x);
  printf ("The arc tangent for (x=%f, y=%f) is %f rad\n", x, y, result );
  return 0;
}
```

[image]

The above case is applicable when we know the x and y value to find the quadrant. What if we know the vector, and use them to find the angle?

For example, we know two vectors. Is there any example function that would take the two vectors, 
works a similar way to:  **`atan2 (y_value,x_value);`**

Comment: You want to find the angle of the intersection of 2 vectors?

Comment: Are you asking how to find the angle between two vectors? That would just be `atan2 (y_value_2,x_value_2) - atan2 (y_value_1,x_value_1)`, though it's not the most efficient way.

Comment: I would like to perform the same operation that `atan2()` does, which is indeed finding an angle (for example we will have a negative angle for the third quadrant ).  Instead of the y and x components in the  atan2() function, I would like to have the components from the vector. 
 
  Finding just an angle may not give the positive and negative angle I guess?

Comment: This is basic (school boy/girl) math.    The cosine of the angle between any two vectors is equal to their dot product divided by the product of their lengths.   The sine of that angle is the magnitude of their cross product divided by the product of their lengths.   So the tangent is given by the magnitude of their cross product divided by their dot product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find angle between vectors in 2D, namely angle needed to rotate the first vector to make it collinear with the second one:

```
angle = atan2(cross(a, b), dot(a, b))
```

where `cross` and `dot` refer to cross product and dot product of vectors. In components:

```
angle = atan2(a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x, a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y)
```

Comment: It's the magnitude of the cross product.   The cross product of two vectors is a vector, not a scalar.

Comment: @Peter they are considering the z component of the resulting vector. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143354/numerically-stable-method-for-angle-between-3d-vectors/1782769) the magnitude is used, though.

Comment: @Bob__    Doesn't change my point - the answer has stated that the angle is given by the arctangent of the cross product divided by the dot product.

Comment: @Peter Note that vectors are in 2D here. Cross product of 2d vectors is considered as scalar value. Magnitude usage is not quite correct - it looses information about sign.

Comment: The cross product of two vectors in 2D (x,y) space is a vector parallel to the z axis.   It is not "considered" as a scalar value, and labeling a scalar as the cross product is flat out wrong.    The scalar value you are using is the Z component of the cross product.   When using magnitude of cross product to calculate the angle, the sign of the dot product accounts for the direction of the cross product (for the two vectors in 2D space, whether the cross product points toward positive or negative z).